# Firebase iOS Facebook Simple Login error

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, firebase

I have same issue following link

[Firebase simple login in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909431/firebase-simple-login-in-ios)

I've already done correct procedure for getting login on Facebook by simple login library but have error message "A third-party provider error occurred. See data for details"

Sorry for my poor English. Anybody knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This issue has resolved myself.Thanks

Comment: How did you fix it? Can you share your fix for others to find?

Comment: True, how did you fix it?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I just forgot to change Facebook app ID and app secret on Firebase Dashboard. maybe you need to check Firebase dashboard simple login, registration for Facebook app ID, updating .plist and put correct openURL at AppDelegate.

Comment: I tried restricting access of my app to Facebook then switching it back again. Surprisingly, it solve this issue but I don't know how...

Answer (score 1):

Double check your Facebook app ID and app secret on Firebase Dashboard.

The values need to agree between the Firebase dashboard login section, registration for Facebook app ID, and your openURL in your AppDelegate .plist.

(The original poster found a solution and posted is to the comments. I've pasted / reworded it here for easier discovery)